# What is the minimum manpower required for A320 start up airline

Tags: safety, airline-operations, commercial-operations, caa-uk-regulations, low-cost-carrier

Ideally on a A320 aircraft how many captains, first officers and cabin cre would be required for a start up airline accounting for 2 Management Captains, standby, training, sickness, leave, mandatory 8 days off.
Thanks MAS

Comment: Sounds a bit more like business related as opposed to aviation related.

Comment: @CarloFelicione is the business side of aviation off topic then?

Comment: It depends on the cancellation rate you wish to achieve and the schedule of the plane. At minimum 2 people.

Comment: If the FAA regulates it, I would accept it as aviation-related.

Comment: How many airplanes?  How many routes?  Way too many unknowns to answer...

Comment: The question is clear, and about aviation. The answer won't be opinion based. but competency based. Whoever thinks that starting an airline just requires an opinion and no expertise or research...Voting to keep open.

Answer (score 0):

The [FAA regs Part 121](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airline_certification/air_carrier) apply to regularly scheduled carriers, and contain all the requirements to obtain an operating certificate. Most entities who want to get into this business hire one or more consultanta with experience in the certification process. Just the required manuals and documentation can rise to thousands of pages. Not for the faint of heart.